# Cloud integration business AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, aws-sdk, business-logic

Would it be possible to make a business where you help companies integrate to the cloud, e.g. AWS and charge them for assisting/supporting the integration to AWS?

Answer (score 1):

yes , 
they will charge extra for Technical Support and also there are some third party vendors available in market for support and bulling

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

[Such companies already exist](https://aws.amazon.com/devops/partner-solutions/).

Comment: Thank you for the link, was basically what i was looking for.